# Graphics3D loses interactivity in Dialog window

Tags: front-end, graphics3d, dialog-window

Is there a way to keep `Graphics3D` objects manipulable when they are embedded in a Dialog window (`CreateDialog`,`DialogInput`, etc)?

I am aware that `CreateDialog` sets `Deployed->True` by default. Setting `Deployed->False` allows the rotation cursor to appear on mouseover, but the object still does not respond to interaction. Is there a way to restore interactivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it `Selectable`:

```
DialogInput[
  Graphics3D[Cuboid[]
  , SphericalRegion -> True
  , BaseStyle -> {Selectable -> True, Deployed -> False} (*!*)
  ]
]
```

`Deployed` is used too as it interferes with `Selectable`.

Comment: Aha! Very interesting, and as you said, just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: It may also be more aesthetically pleasing to use `SphericalRegion -> True`

Comment: Another incremental improvement: wrapping the `Graphics3D` inside a `Grid` (or similar) and setting `Selectable->True` for that `Grid` is preferable, as it removes the undesirable side effect of the rest of the dialog window being selectable. Mike, thanks for the tip re: `SphericalRegion->True`. Combining this with `RotationAction->"Clip"` produces an aesthetically pleasing result that does not attempt to resize the window when the Graphics3D is rotated.